# BigQuery Deadline Exceeded and RuntimeException

Tags: google-bigquery

When I am running a query which I am confident the result set isn't that large. I keep getting this error, can someone explain what causes this error and how can I change my query to avoid this (other than selecting less data because that is not something I am able to change for this query)

Error preparing subsidiary query: com.google.storage.megastore.exception.DeadlineExceededRuntimeException: Deadline exceeded: Deadline

my query is basically selecting data for a month and then applying a case clause and a group by. There are no joins

Here is a cleaned up version of my query. Most of the columns are just strings.

```
select
counted,
CONCAT(user_id,"_",string(index)) as user_id,
name,
-- We want to give each event an alias here, so the first event in the funnel would be called step1
case when name="16" and param7 = "b" then 'step1'
when name="71" then 'step2'
when name="73" then 'step3'
when name="10" and param7= "b" and param1="a" then 'step4'
when name="18" then 'step5'
when name="31" then 'step6'
else 'na'
end as step
from (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([tablename_],TIMESTAMP('2016-04-01'),TIMESTAMP('2016-05-01')))
-- selects all of the 6 steps in the funnel.
WHERE (name = "16" AND param7 = "b") OR (name = "71") OR (name = "73") OR (name="10" AND param7 = "b" AND  param1 = "a") OR (name = "18") OR (name = "31")
```

Comment: could you please post your query? is it run on ga_sessions default tables? does it happen to all of your queries or just this specific one?

Comment: does your query succeed for just one day vs. whole month?

Comment: One day *sometimes works. It seems like it's the case clause that's causing this. I removed it and added a bunch of raw columns to display and increased the time range to two month and I haven't run into the error since. That is really strange, since the case clause is just a short string evaluation. -- Maybe it's dying because it's selecting the data and manipulating/testing it with the case clause on the same stage? So it would be better if I select first and then wrap around it and then do the case clause? This is just a theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility raised by a coworker was the fact that I was using the function
TABLE DATE RANGE which messes up something about the query causing it to fail, he suggested typing up each individual table, so in this case 30 tables and it did remove the error as well and I noticed that the queries were faster too. Not sure why and it is a pain to have a giant query because you have to have 1 line for each date you want to query in the FROM clause

```
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([tablename_],TIMESTAMP('2016-04-01'),TIMESTAMP('2016-05-01')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment - you should try

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    counted,
    CONCAT(user_id,"_",STRING(index)) AS user_id,
    name,
    -- We want to give each event an alias here, so the first event in the funnel would be called step1
    CASE 
      WHEN name="16" AND param7 = "b" THEN 'step1'
      WHEN name="71" THEN 'step2'
      WHEN name="73" THEN 'step3'
      WHEN name="10" AND param7= "b" AND param1="a" THEN 'step4'
      WHEN name="18" THEN 'step5'
      WHEN name="31" THEN 'step6'
      ELSE 'na'
    END AS step
  FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([tablename_],TIMESTAMP('2016-04-01'),TIMESTAMP('2016-05-01')))
)
-- leave only those 6 steps in the funnel.
WHERE step != 'na'
```

Comment: Ya that's what I did and it's been working consistently. It's a REALLY weird bug. Someone else suggested it maybe due to table_date_range not working correctly and I need to enumerate all of the dates, but I don't think that is the reason.